# using php in css ,substr_count() seach file location

Tags: php, css

i have some question about php in css 
[my projet folde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXfpr.png)

What i'm trying to do : count `<li>` with php in css 
Probleme : cannot find the right location

more information : `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.php">` in my "head.php"

in my style.php

```
<?php
  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
  $menu="../index.php";
  $li=substr_count($menu,"<li>");
  echo $menu;
?>
```

i tried "../index.php"; "../inc/menu.php"; "./inc/menu.php"; 
no one work

Comment: Hi not sure what you are asking but i think you need to use file_get_contents to load the file before use substr_count , http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: @KanishkaPanamaldeniya ho thanks . right i'm dumb .. i had set my file location to string ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
$menu = file_get_contents('../index.php');
$liCount = substr_count($menu,'<li>');
echo $liCount;
```